# How to view a runnable .jar's output via SSH client

Tags: java, unix, ssh, terminal, putty

I have a .jar runnable running on my server. When I run the file locally I am able to see its output via my IDE. Similarly I can connect via SSH and run the file and see the output,  but when I close the session the JAR exits.

Is there any way to have my application continuously running and then tapping into the java applications output using a terminal service like SSH without having to stop/start the application.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have discovered TMUX since my question. I would highly recommend it to anyone wanting to run a remote session of a java console app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either `screen` or `nohup`

What is happening is that when you close your SSH session, there is a hangup call made to the program.

You could use nohup. Nohup stands for "no hangup"

```
nohup java -jar myJar.jar > outputFile.txt
```

That would run the program in the backround and send all output to `outputFile.txt`. When you end your session it will continue running. You must use a `kill` command to kill it.

The second option is you could use `screen` which essentually creates a detachable "ghost session". When you run screen it looks like you are in a different ssh session. Then when you detach from screen, the processes continues in the backround. When you exit your ssh session, screen continues to run.
You simply ssh back into the server, and re-attach to your screen session, and like magic, your program is still running with all relevent output. A simple read on the man page should catch you up on how to do this.

```
man screen
```

Lastly, I decided to add this third option, not because its viable, but simply so you can understand that it is an option. (Some people would claim this is the only REAL option as it is what your SUPPOSED to do. Frankly I couldn't care less and think you should do whatever is the easiest to get to your goal.)

You can also edit your program to swallow the hangup signal. The program would then always run in the backround. You can then use

```
java -jar myJar.jar & > outputFile.com
```

The `&` tells the command to start a new process (aka run in the backround) and the `>` sends the output to a file. This is how normal server applications like tomcat or spring boot work. They simply swallow the hangup call.

Comment: Perfect answer. This is exactly what I was looking for. 10 out 10 :-)